# Get resource directory (similar to App.GetResourceStream)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to access a directory with resources files, similar to `App.GetResourceStream`? Intention: I have a directory of images, which is constantly being extended and I want to be able to traverse through those images to get the names of all available files.

Comment: If you mean contents then no. Check this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530777/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-assets-in-the-wp7-content-project

Comment: Yes, contents. Question answered. Thank you!